# MATLAB Plotting. Error - Inner Matrix Must Agree

Tags: matlab, plot

I have tried to plot this for a very long time now. I still don't understand why it does not work here but is working on my calculator.

The Equation is consists of one sin function and one cosine function. Both of them depend on the independent variable 't' and the common factor is e^(-0.05*t)
I have attached a picture of the Equation.[image: Math Equation]

```
t = linspace(0,20,501);
thetta = (exp(-0.05*t))*(((pi/20)*(cos(3.13*t)) + (0.02458*(sin(3.13*t)))))
plot(t, thetta, 'x')
```

Comment: Did you google the error message? There are literally hundreds of questions like this on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to do element-wise multiplication between the exponential term and the rest as indicated below:

term = ((pi/20)*(cos(3.13*t)) + (0.02458*(sin(3.13*t))));
theta = exp(-0.05*t) .* term;